# How to use click event on Y-axis label in angular Gantt chart High Chart

Tags: angular, highcharts, gantt-chart

How to add click event on Y-axis label in Gantt chart. It's working fine in javascript but not in angular. In angular giving following error "Type '{ events: { click: () => void; }; }' is not assignable to type 'YAxisLabelsOptions'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'events' does not exist in type 'YAxisLabelsOptions'". Using 9.3.x version of the highcharts lib.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOaPR.png)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-gantt-jxcjsz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `highcharts-custom-events` module doesn't extend types for Highcharts, so you need to create your own types. For example:

```
interface ExtendedYAxisLabelsOptions extends Highcharts.YAxisLabelsOptions {
  events: YAxisLabelsEvents
}

interface YAxisLabelsEvents {
  click(): void;
}

export class AppComponent {
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;

  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    ...,
    yAxis: {
      labels: {
        events: {
          click: function() { console.log(this) } 
        } 
      } as ExtendedYAxisLabelsOptions, 
      ...
    }
  };
}
```

---

**Live example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-gantt-jyyhro?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts